# iOS Detect No Network Connectivity

Tags: iphone, ios

If an iPhone does not have network connection or is in flight mode, would the canOpenURL return a no for the "tel://" URL?

Comment: checkout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the iPhone can still open the phone app and make calls without a network connection.

Look at the Reachability example code on the Apple dev site.